# mysql logging turned on but not displaying in terminal

Tags: mysql, logging, ubuntu

I'd like to turn on logging in mysql, and have the results of the log dumped to screen as I'm navigating a web app that has a backend mysql database.
I have:

1. Edited my my.cnf file located in /etc/mysql/.  Ensured that the following two lines exist under the Logging and Replication section:

   ```
       general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
       general_log             = 1
   ```
2. Restarted mysql.
3. typed 'tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log' at the command prompt

And then i tried surfing my app to see if it would record the different sql statements that are being executed.  I don't get anything dumped to the screen except for:

```
  /usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
  Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

I've also tried:

```
    touch /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

and

```
    chown mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql/mysql*
```

to make sure mysql has access / permissions to the file. 
Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to create the file and add permissions, maybe file does not exists and MySQL doesn't have priviledges to create one

Comment: the file /var/log/mysql/mysql.log does exist... but it only contains the types of messages i've posted above.  Thanks for the suggestion though, Mihai.